# Firefox Windows / Linux inconstancies

Tags: css, linux, firefox, fonts, font-face

[My website](http://www.samplerbox.org) has very different rendering in Firefox Windows / Firefox Linux (however, similar versions, default parameters for both).

The reason seems to be that the font are rendered very differently. This:

```
font-family: sans-serif;
```

gives Arial-like font on Windows:

[image]

and a little bit different font on Linux:

[image]

---

**How to solve this problem and have constant rendering in Firefox Win / Firefox Linux ?**
(if possible, I'd like to keep the Windows rendering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have defined the font name `sans-serif` which is not a font per se, just tells the browser to use *any* sans serif font the browser prefers. But even if you give a concrete font name, be aware that the installed fonts in Win / Linux are not the same. Also, the font rendering is OS dependant, so both OS might render fonts a bit differently. The best way to solve this would be to use a web font, where you have the same font files for both Win and Linux. Also gives you a lot more freedom in design, since you do not have to rely on the fonts the OS provides.

But even then, it can happen that the user chooses to use a bigger font size, and you still have rendering differences, but not as visible as with your example where you apparently have two completely different fonts.

In other words: achieving a result where each font rendering looks *exactly* the same is simply impossible. Thats the nature of the www.

Comment: Thanks! Impossible to use Arial on Linux I imagine? (except if I install it manually, but I won't do this for each visitor of my website ;) )

Comment: Yes, you got it. But why use Arial? So boring ;) And btw, what do you mean by "Linux"? There are so many variants of it.

Comment: In this example (screenshots in my question), Arial looks much more balanced than the heavy-looking Firefox Ubuntu rendering.
What do you use usually use instead of `font-family: sans-serif;` to provide better consistancy? Do you have an example?

Comment: Sorry, I think there is no better consistency in this case. On Mac vs Win, you would do the following: `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`, since "Arial" is really a clone of "Helvetica". So you tell the browser to use Arial, then Helvetica (if Arial was not found) and then _any_ sans serif as a fallback. But on Ubuntu, there is not even Helvetica installed. And Ubuntu is only _one_ Linux variant. So again, if this is really that important for you, use your _own_ custom font face, so that at least all browsers show the same font-family.

Comment: Ok. How to use my *own* custom font face?
Oh, something else: I don't really mind the font itself, but I really mind the **width** of this text. How to have at least the same width for `Forum` text in my example (see question) with both Linux and Windows?

Comment: You can add an individual font-face by using `@font-face`. Of course you have to provide some matching font files either by hosting it on your own or using some kind of cdn. More information here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webfonts/quick/

And the width of the font is determined by the font itself. Do not try to modify this using some trickery, it will look bad anyway.

Comment: Ok! Last thing: if the width of the font is determined by the font itself, then, as I have **no control** about what font is used for `font-family: sans-serif;` the result will be bad:  [this](http://samplerbox.org/) looks ok on Windows, but on Linux, the logo+menu will take two-lines, in a bad layout.... How would you deal with that?

Comment: Well, you might still have problems with a vertically oriented menu like this, if you do not leave enough space on the left for it to grow - for example the same will happen if the user opts to use a bigger font size, or your viewport is too narrow. And as I said, you can at least improve the display by using a custom font, so the differences between platforms will be not as big then (and look much more like the same). And yes, you can mark this question as solved ;) Think this is all you can do about it.